# Sync Protractor with an Angular app hosted inside an iframe by a non-Angular website

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I'm having trouble accessing elements via methods such as `by.binding()`.

The project setup is as follows:

```
Non-angular website
|
--> Iframe
    |
    --> Angular app
```

Here's a snippet of what I'm trying to do:

```
// Disable sync
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

// Navigate to non-angular website
browser.driver.get('http://non-angular.com');

// Switch to angular app (inside the iframe)
browser.switchTo().frame('angular-iframe');

// Search for an element
browser.driver.findElement(by.id('title')); // -> Works

element(by.binding('model.title')); // -> Fails 
UnknownError: unknown error: [ng:test] no injector found for element argument to getTestability
```

Any idea of what I'm missing here?

Comment: What if you set `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;` after switching to an iframe?

Comment: Also, try tweaking `rootElement` config setting.

Comment: After setting `ignoreSynchronization` to `false` I get the following error: `Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "angular could not be found on the window"`. Note that angular **is** available inside the iframe window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the problem wasn't to do with Non-Angular website + Iframe. It was instead caused by Angular being bootstrapped manually.

All I had to do is tell Protractor to wait until Angular was available on the page and ready to be synced with.

Comment: Do you mean you've just called `waitForAngular()`?

Comment: No quite like that. The HTML template containing the `ng-app` is injected async into the page. So after it's injected I set a flag to `true` and in the Protractor test I wait until this flag is valid. I guess it could be neater but `waitForAngular()` didn't work for me.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing! Happy protractoring.